# Flattening an array of ActiveRecord::Relation instances

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I wanted to convert a nested array of `ActiveRecord::Relation` objects, like this:

```
# Event is a ActiveRecord::Base derived class
r1 = [ [ Event.where(id: 1) ], Event.where(id: 1)]
# => [ [ #<ActiveRecord::Relation []> ], #<ActiveRecord::Relation[]> ]
```

into:

```
[#<ActiveRecord::Relation []>, #<ActiveRecord::Relation []> ]
```

`Array#flatten` is designed to do this perfectly. Unfortunately, it does not return the expected result:

```
r1.flatten # => []
```

`Enumrable#map` does not work either:

```
r1.map{|m| m.limit(10) } # => []
```

`Enumerable#flat_map` returns a little different result:

```
r1.flat_map{|m| m.limit(10) } # => [ #<ActiveRecord::Relation []> ]
```

Finally, looping over the array and pushing into another empty array returns the expected result:

```
z = []
r1.each {|e| if e.is_a?(Array) then e.each{|x| z << x} else z << e end}
# => [#<ActiveRecord::Relation []>, #<ActiveRecord::Relation []> ]
```

What causes these differences?

I'm using

- ruby 2.0.0p353 (2013-11-22 revision 43784) [x86_64-darwin13.0.0]
- (built with gcc via RVM + Homebrew)
- Rails 4.0.2
- MacOS X Mavericks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you perform a `.flatten`, the method will trigger the SQL query wrapped by the Relations to be executed. The result of the queries will then be flattened.

In your case, it looks like both queries returned an empty recordset causing

```
r1 = [ [ Event.where(id: 1) ], Event.where(id: 1)]
```

to be evaluated as

```
r1 = [ [[]] , []]
```

that indeeds flattens as

```
[]
```

If you try the code with a scope that produces a result, then you will see that the flatten will return the array of records.

In order to flatten the scopes, you need a custom method like you did. Here's an enhanced version that works with illimitate levels.

```
def flatten_scopes(scopes)
  scopes.inject([]) { |a,r| r.is_a?(Array) ? a += flatten_scopes(r) : a.push(r) }
end

flatten_scopes(r1)
```

Comment: Thanks. Right. Will introduce similar methods to somewhere suitable.

Answer (score 2):

You're getting the result you're seeing because when you enumerate the relation (or convert it to an array), it doesn't contain any elements.

You can see this in the printout of the relation, which has the `[]` just before the `>`. If there were anything in it, you'd see the elements within the brackets.